# PyCharm unresolved reference

Tags: pycharm

I'm having a fairly weird problem with PyCharm at the moment. The famous unresolved reference problem. I have done the steps which have been encouraged in previous solution to similar problems:

1. Set source root
2. Check interpreter
3. Made sure `Add source roots to PYTHONPATH` was on
4. Invalidate cache and reset

None of these have worked out, and its my first time not being able to solve it simply by setting the source root. I am using a virtualenv which I have created simply using `virtualenv venv` and `pip install Django`. While also adding it as the PyCharm interpreter.

This is a standard beginner Django project with a single `frontpage` application, which is of course included in the `settings.py` file.

**Picture of the include that is not found**

[image]

I have also tried reinstalling PyCharm without any luck.
So if anyone have any suggestion on how I can trace down this problem I'd love to hear it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't imported `frontpage` anywhere... so PyCharm is doing the right thing. You can do this, but I think you need to quote it like this, as the docstring in your picture indicates:

```
include('frontpage.urls')
```

Otherwise you could `import frontpage` and then `frontpage.urls` would be in scope.

The "unresolved reference problem" that most people refer to (at least, I ran into it over and over again) involves things being flagged in the imports as not being found on the path. It takes a little bit of fiddling to make sure everything is in place to get a clean inspection.

Comment: Omg... You have no idea how long I've been sitting with this... I just couldn't figure out why PyCharm wouldn't let me use include.... THANK YOU! :)

Comment: @PhyCoMath No problem. I love Python and Pycharm and Django.

Comment: Yeah, me too, but today it annoyed me A LOT. Such a simple mistake, haha.